# Unable to register node using selenium grid on multiple virtual machines

Tags: selenium, grid

I am trying to do a scenario, where I have my scripts on one VM (Win 7). I start the hub on this VM using: start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub 10.0.3.15:8000/grid/register

I also start a IE9 browser node on this VM using: java -Dwebdriver.iexplore.driver='IEDriverServer.exe' -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role webDriver -hub localhost:4444/grid/console -browser "browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS,version=9" -port 5555

The next thing I need to do is: start a IE8 browser node on another VM with Win XP: I use the below: java -Dwebdriver.iexplore.driver='IEDriverServer.exe' -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role webdriver -hub 169.254.204.90:5555/grid/console -browser "browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS,version=8" - port 5556

But it doesn't seem to start the node on the second VM. I am really stuck and trying to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: any specific errors printed out?

Comment: Why does the hub ip and port change form `10.0.3.15:8000` to `169.254.204.90:5555`

Comment: Ok so i changed my IP address for the hub to match and ran it from the VM, and it is now registering the nodes to the grid.

Comment: So now that i have the nodes registered on the grid and i have browsers running, how do i start running the selenium scripts on each of them parallely? any ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can run them in parallel using testng or junit, I need more information about how are you running them.

For testng, you can read the documentation here: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

As an example:

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
```